# Find query in mongodb from specified array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, find

I have two JSON document on a mongo collection

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("asdf"), "employee" : {"name": "Bob"}}
{"_id" : ObjectId("1234"), "employee" : {"name": "Rob"}}
```

All i just wanted to make a simple query get the name of the employee from my array.

I tried

```
db.myCollection.find({"employee.name": "Bob"})
```

This works and returns only 1 document.

```
db.myCollection.find({"employee.name": ["Bob", "Rob"]})
```

Doesnt work. Doesnt return anything

```
db.myCollection.find({"employee.name": "Bob", "Rob"})
```

Syntax error

```
db.myCollection.find({"employee.name": {$all : ["Bob", "Rob"]} })
```

Doesnt work. Doesnt return anything

I know this is a very simple query. But couldn't figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `$in` operator, see the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/)

```
db.myCollection.find({"employee.name":{$in:["Bob","Rob"]}} )
```

The `$all` operator doesn't return any documents, as it selects the documents where the value of a field is an array that contains all the specified elements. The following record would satisfy this condition:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("asdf"), "employee" : {"name": ["Bob","Rob"]}}
```

The above record would also be returned by this query:

```
db.myCollection.find({"employee.name": ["Bob", "Rob"]})
```

Finally, the query below throws an invalid syntax error as `{"employee.name": "Bob", "Rob"}` is not a valid JSON\BSON document:

```
db.myCollection.find({"employee.name": "Bob", "Rob"})
```

Comment: Worked like charm :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using [$in](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/) operator

**query** : `db.myCollection.find({"employee.name":  { $in: ["Bob", "Rob"] }})`

For the options you tried,

```
db.myCollection.find({"employee.name": "Bob"})
```

> This will return the records with name having "Bob", so that is why it is returning only one record.

```
db.myCollection.find({"employee.name": ["Bob", "Rob"]})
```

> For this option we have provided ["Bob", "Rob"] for matching value, which actually is and array, so it will return records with same array in name.

```
db.myCollection.find({"employee.name": "Bob", "Rob"})
```

> For this option, as Jaco said it is not a valid json format.

```
db.myCollection.find({"employee.name": {$all : ["Bob", "Rob"]} })
```

> This option will try to find records with value of name field as an array such that the value array contains all the values provided in `$all`

Answer (score 0):

According to above mentioned description as an alternate solution to it please try executing following query assuming that all documents need to be fetched

db.getCollection('myCollection').find({},{_id:0,'employee.name':1})

The above query fetches all documents from collection utilizing **projection document** to retrieve specific fields in resultset

For more detailed desciption regarding MongoDB projection document please refer the following documentation as mentioned in following URL

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/